# Error in handling a post request (Express, MySql, Postman

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

When I'm trying to send a POST request using Postman, it gives me this error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'product_title')"

```
app.post("/product", async (req, res, next) => {
  let product = {
    product_title: req.body.product_title,
    product_price: req.body.product_price,
    product_type: req.body.product_type,
    product_brand: req.body.product_brand,
  };
  let sql = `INSERT INTO products SET ?`;

  await db.query(sql, product, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(result);
  });

  res.send("Added");
});
```

Comment: In the postman check the spelling of product_title

Comment: `req.body` is `undefined`, you probably didn't use any body parser

Comment: Oh, right. I almost forgot that. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

use `?` keyword

```
  app.post("/product", async (req, res, next) => {
  let product = {
    product_title: req.body?.product_title,
    product_price: req.body?.product_price,
    product_type: req.body?.product_type,
    product_brand: req.body?.product_brand,
  };
  let sql = `INSERT INTO products SET ?`;

  await db.query(sql, product, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(result);
  });

  res.send("Added");
});
```

Comment: I have used body-parser and it worked.

Comment: Ok , but you need validation req.body to sure exist variables in object

Comment: You're just telling typescript to ignore an error that didn't even happen in the first place. OP's issue is a runtime issue.